Close option should allow stackoverflow.com
There was a question about using QuantLib in Python. As of this writing, there are 665 questions on Stackoverflow concerning the tag QuantLib. 
I'd like to recommend that when someone closes a topic that the exchanges where the question is better include both stackoverflow (new) and quantitative finance meta (as is current).

Please also take note of the comment by @Ana attached to the question.

Thanks for the reference. I've upvoted stackoverflow.
